# replace and cast for comparison

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am using PHP to take the price and size criteria of a search form and build the MySQL query below. The price field in the table is an INT, lease field is FLOAT and size field is VARCHAR because the value contains the unit of measure.

The query below runs with the PHP script and returns zero records. I run it directly on the table and it returns 173 records. When I run it directly, I replace the PDO placeholders with **0** for the minimums of both, **10000000** for **max price**, **1000** for **max size**, **ft** for **size_unit0**, **sqft** for **size_unit1**, and it returns 173 records. From what I could find without any conditions except that it is a Retail business, there should be 9 records.

I did a var_dump on the values that replace the size_unit placeholders in the PHP code and they are float.

The table imports data from the real estate association, which is why the size field is VARCHAR.

I'm baffled.

QUERY

```
SELECT lt.Price, lt.Lease, lt.LeasePerUnit,
    IF (lt.Price >= :minimum_price AND
        lt.Price <= :maximum_price,
        REPLACE(
            FORMAT(lt.Price, 2), ".00", ""),
            CONCAT(REPLACE(FORMAT(lt.Lease, 2), ".00", ""), "/", lt.LeasePerUnit)
        ) AS DisplayPrice,
    IF (lt.Price >= :minimum_price AND
        lt.Price <= :maximum_price,
        REPLACE(lt.Price, ".00", ""), REPLACE(lt.Lease, ".00", "")
        ) AS DisplayPriceSort,
    lt.ListingId AS MlsNumber, lt.PropertyId, lt.PropertyType,
    lt.StreetAddress AS Address, lt.City, lt.PublicRemarks,
    lt.ListAgent1Id, lt.ListAgent2Id

    FROM listings AS lt
    WHERE 1 = 1 AND lt.PropertyType = "Retail"
        AND (
            (lt.Price >= :minimum_price AND lt.Price <= :maximum_price) OR
            (lt.Lease >= :minimum_price AND lt.Lease <= :maximum_price)
        )
        AND (
            (
                REPLACE(lt.SizeFrontage, ' :size_unit0', '') >= :minimum_size
                AND REPLACE(lt.SizeFrontage, ' :size_unit0', '') <= :maximum_size
            ) OR
            (
                REPLACE(lt.SizeInterior, ' :size_unit0', '') >= :minimum_size
                AND REPLACE(lt.SizeInterior, ' :size_unit0', '') <= :maximum_size
            ) OR
            (
                REPLACE(lt.SizeTotal, ' :size_unit0', '') >= :minimum_size
                AND REPLACE(lt.SizeTotal, ' :size_unit0', '') <= :maximum_size
            ) OR
            (
                REPLACE(lt.SizeFrontage, ' :size_unit1', '') >= :minimum_size
                AND REPLACE(lt.SizeFrontage, ' :size_unit1', '') <= :maximum_size
            ) OR
            (
                REPLACE(lt.SizeInterior, ' :size_unit1', '') >= :minimum_size
                AND REPLACE(lt.SizeInterior, ' :size_unit1', '') <= :maximum_size
            ) OR
            (
                REPLACE(lt.SizeTotal, ' :size_unit1', '') >= :minimum_size
                AND REPLACE(lt.SizeTotal, ' :size_unit1', '') <= :maximum_size
            )
        )

    ORDER BY DisplayPriceSort * 1 DESC
```

applicable PHP CODE creating query

```
if (isset($minimum_price) && isset($maximum_price) && !isset($featured_mls_number) && !isset($mls_number))
{
    if ($transaction_type != '')
    {
        if ($transaction_type == 'for_lease')
        {
            $where .= ' AND (lt.Lease >= :minimum_price AND lt.Lease <= :maximum_price)';
        }
        elseif ($transaction_type == 'for_sale')
        {
            $where .= ' AND (lt.Price >= :minimum_price AND lt.Price <= :maximum_price)';
        }
    }
    elseif (($transaction_type != '' && $transaction_type == 'for_sale_or_rent') || $transaction_type == '')
    {
        $where .= ' AND ((lt.Price >= :minimum_price AND lt.Price <= :maximum_price) OR (lt.Lease >= :minimum_price AND lt.Lease <= :maximum_price))';
    }
    $execute_array[':minimum_price'] = $minimum_price;
    $execute_array[':maximum_price'] = $maximum_price;
}
else
{
    $execute_array[':minimum_price'] = 0;
    $execute_array[':maximum_price'] = 100000000;
}
if (isset($minimum_size) && isset($maximum_size) && !isset($featured_mls_number) && !isset($mls_number))
{
    #SizeFrontage, SizeInterior, SizeTotal
    foreach ($size_units_array as $su_key => $su_value)
    {
        $size_unit_lower = strtolower($su_key);
        if ($size_unit_lower == $size_unit)
        {
            $where .= " AND (";
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($su_value); $i++)
            {
                $where .=
                "
                (REPLACE(lt.SizeFrontage, CONCAT(' ', :size_unit".$i."), '') >= :minimum_size
                AND REPLACE(lt.SizeFrontage, CONCAT(' ', :size_unit".$i."), '') <= :maximum_size)
                OR (REPLACE(lt.SizeInterior, CONCAT(' ', :size_unit".$i."), '') >= :minimum_size
                AND REPLACE(lt.SizeInterior, CONCAT(' ', :size_unit".$i."), '') <= :maximum_size)
                OR (REPLACE(lt.SizeTotal, CONCAT(' ', :size_unit".$i."), '') >= :minimum_size
                AND REPLACE(lt.SizeTotal, CONCAT(' ', :size_unit".$i."), '') <= :maximum_size)
                ";
                $execute_array[':size_unit'.$i] = $su_value[$i];
                if ($i != count($su_value) - 1) $where .= " OR ";
            }
            $where .= ")";
        }
        $execute_array[':minimum_size'] = $minimum_size;
        $execute_array[':maximum_size'] = $maximum_size;
    }
}

$query =
'
    SELECT lt.Price, lt.Lease, lt.LeasePerUnit,
    IF (lt.Price >= :minimum_price AND lt.Price <= :maximum_price,
    REPLACE(FORMAT(lt.Price, 2), ".00", ""), CONCAT(REPLACE(FORMAT(lt.Lease, 2),
    ".00", ""), "/", lt.LeasePerUnit)) AS DisplayPrice,
    IF (lt.Price >= :minimum_price AND lt.Price <= :maximum_price,
    REPLACE(lt.Price, ".00", ""), REPLACE(lt.Lease, ".00", "")) AS DisplayPriceSort,
    lt.ListingId AS MlsNumber, lt.PropertyId, lt.PropertyType,
    lt.StreetAddress AS Address, lt.City, lt.BedroomsTotal, lt.BathroomTotal,
    lt.PublicRemarks, lt.ListAgent1Id, lt.ListAgent2Id,
    ListAgent1OfficeName, ListAgent2OfficeName
    FROM listings AS lt
    WHERE '.$where.'
    ORDER BY '.$sort_by.'
';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised you're not seeing the error message

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

PDO will not bind variables to your `:size_unitN` parameters because they are inside single quotes in the SQL query. This means they are being treated as the literal string " :size_unitN".

Instead you should move the parameters outside the quoted string and prepend spaces to them using `CONCAT`, for example

```
REPLACE(lt.SizeFrontage, ' :size_unit0', '') >= :minimum_size
```

should be replaced with:

```
REPLACE(lt.SizeFrontage, CONCAT(' ', :size_unit0), '') >= :minimum_size
```

If the size data is always in the format an integer followed by a space followed by an alphabetic unit, it may not be necessary to use the `REPLACE` function at all. If you expressly bind your minimum_size and maximum_size values as integers, MySQL will cast the columns to integers as well to do the comparison. For example

```
$q = $pdo->prepare(
    "SELECT * FROM listings WHERE SizeFrontage > :min AND SizeFrontage < :max");
$q->bindValue(":min", 10, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$q->bindValue(":max", 35, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

You should consider improving the data model. At the moment your query is going to be quite inefficient. If you stored the sizes as integers in the database, they would be faster to search especially as you could index the fields. This may be a particular concern if you have a large number of records.

If the records are stored in the database using different units (eg some in square metres, some in square feet) you will only be able to search for some of them at any one time using the `REPLACE` syntax, and you will get incorrect results using `PDO::PARAM_INT`. A better approach would be to convert all the sizes to one unit before saving them in the database, then convert the user's request to the same unit as necessary.

Comment: Thanks Matt. Unfortunately, still not working properly. Via PHP 1 record now and via the table directly still 173 records. I replaced the REPLACE MySQL code for all size fields/PDO placeholders as suggested.

Comment: Can you provide the code you're using to bind the parameters and fetch the results?

Comment: Updated the original post with it.

Comment: That code looks fine. It's a bit hard to test out of context but it should work the same as directly in SQL now. Returning one result is particularly odd. Is it the first row that you get executing the SQL manually? Are you certain there isn't a fault with the logic for iterating over the resultset? I've also had some further thoughts about your problem which I have added to my answer.

Comment: I ended up changing how those columns are imported from the real estate association. I separated the value and unit into their own columns. The results are now correct either way with 10 records. The database model needs an overhaul. It was initially created with very limited time to get it done. Thanks again.